# Finding start and end timestamp for values above defined level in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that includes just the following fields:
timestamp, level 
(timestamptz, double precision)
The table is being feeded by data from a sensor that measures voltage of realtime signal. Sampling frequency is 1 Hz.
Real sample data is following:

```
`2016-05-23 08:00:00+02 | 44.0
 2016-05-23 08:00:01+02 | 43.9
 2016-05-23 08:00:02+02 | 44.1
 2016-05-23 08:00:03+02 | 54.6
 2016-05-23 08:00:04+02 | 61.0
 2016-05-23 08:00:05+02 | 62.2
 2016-05-23 08:00:06+02 | 63.4
 2016-05-23 08:00:07+02 | 62.9
 2016-05-23 08:00:08+02 | 61.9
 2016-05-23 08:00:09+02 | 63.9
 2016-05-23 08:00:10+02 | 44.2
 2016-05-23 08:00:11+02 | 44.0
 2016-05-23 08:00:12+02 | 61.3
 2016-05-23 08:00:13+02 | 62.4
 2016-05-23 08:00:14+02 | 44.3
 2016-05-23 08:00:15+02 | 43.8'
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to find a timestamp when the voltage exceeded 60 milivolts for at least 3 subsequent samples (in order to suppress random spikes).
 The condition is fulfilled at time `2016-05-23 08:00:06+02` therefore `2016-05-23 08:00:04+02` should be returned as an event start time.
Then I need to find end of the event, the time when voltage drops under 60 mV. But I'd like to suppress random drops, so the correct end timestamp should be `2016-05-23 08:00:13+02`
I tried to write a query that uses Postgresql Window Functions, but no luck.

Comment: IMO the easiest way it to create a stored function and walk through cursor.

Comment: Should the last row be `08:00:12` or `08:00:15`?

Comment: Indeed it should be `08:00:15`. I had some issues with browser and made this copy paste fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution.  Maybe there is room for improvement.

```
SELECT ts,
       voltage,
       case when min(voltage) over (rows between current row and 3 following) > 60 then 'on' end,
       case when max(voltage) over (rows between current row and 3 following) < 60 then 'off' end
FROM data
ORDER BY ts;
```

This gives you results like this:

`ts          | voltage | case | case
---------------------+---------+------+------
 2016-05-23 08:00:00 |      44 |      | off
 2016-05-23 08:00:01 |    43.9 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:02 |    44.1 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:03 |    54.6 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:04 |      61 | on   |
 2016-05-23 08:00:05 |    62.2 | on   |
 2016-05-23 08:00:06 |    63.4 | on   |
 2016-05-23 08:00:07 |    62.9 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:08 |    61.9 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:09 |    63.9 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:10 |    44.2 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:11 |      44 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:12 |    61.3 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:12 |    43.8 |      | off
 2016-05-23 08:00:13 |    62.4 |      |
 2016-05-23 08:00:14 |    44.3 |      | off`

Then as you process this you look for "on" and when you find it you look for the next "off".  (Obviously, a Boolean column would be more efficient, but this is better for illustration.)

Comment: Many thanks for sharing your idea Peter. I did a test on large dataset and it works quite well. Previously I tried to use ROW between current row and... but in some wrong way. The MAX(voltage) is a good solution indeed. Now I have to find a way how pair the right pairs (on and off).